# Google Chrome keeps crashing tabs

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem with Gooogle chrome version 19 on Windows XP.
Every few minutes, some of the tabs crash, showing the "Aw, Sanp!" message.
I read in [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/103292/how-to-fix-shockwave-flash-crashes-in-google-chrome/) that it could be because of the Shockwave flash plugin,
but it doesn't look like the case in my browser.
I don't get any error message, the only thing I see is that some of the tabs randomly change state to the tab with the crash message and than everything works normally until the next random crash.

Does anyone know what could be the problem, or how I could find more about the cause of it?

[image: Chrome's]

Comment: What web packes are crashing? Are the same ones always crash, or you can display this for example: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html without crashing? Try to enable crashing: chrome://crashes and try to be carefoul: chrome://flags/ ...

Comment: I've turned the crash report to ON, I'll post any crashes that it will show.

Comment: Ok, also try disabling anything that seams suspicious here `chrome://flags` like GPU acceleration, and such.

Comment: The crash report is ON, but when it crashes, nothing is added and the crash list is still empty...

Comment: I also checked the flags and everything there is disabled...

Comment: And does it crash when you are opening/refreshing this page: gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html ?

Comment: It doesn't crash on every page or any time, it crashes randomly. The gnu page didn't crash yet, but I did get crashes in the superuser page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step

1. Close the first browser google chrome
2. Open windows explorer and go to address bar
3. Find the file Local State which is in "app data> local> google> chrome> User Data> local state"
4. remove the state where the local file, this file stores some custom settings.
5. Try to reopen google chrome browser and see if the problem can be resolved.

Comment: I'm checking this solution, it removed all my settings, extensions and plugins.  I'll update if it works...

Comment: Worked for me as well, Chromium v26.0.1394.

Comment: Still works today it seems.

Comment: "Some custom settings" it complete breaks everything...............