# Chrome tabs crash after a bit of browsing

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, browser, crash

I already saw [this thread here](https://superuser.com/questions/430487/google-chrome-keeps-crashing-tabs), but neither disabling the Shockwave plugin nor deleting the file `Local State` did work.

When surfing, after about 30 seconds when I open a tab and type in an address like the one from Facebook or reddit or superuser the site stays blank, loads for some time and then crashes. This happens for every page I try to open in every tab.

This is how it looks when loading

[image: screenshot of chrome tab not responding]

and like this when crashed (sorry for the German):

[image: screenshot of chrome tab crashed]

I already:

- Disabled all extensions
- Disabled all plugins
- Deleted the browser data
- Searched for malware (with Antimalware Bytes)
- Restarted chrome and the computer
- Tried different browsers, different tabs, different pages
- Deleted the file `Local State` under `AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/UserData`

I don't know what more to do?

OS: Windows 10 (not happening in Ubuntu in my VM)
Chrome version: `51.0.2704.103 m` (Chrome says it's the most recent version)

Update: Since I left my LastPass password somewhere where I'm currently not I would want to avoid to reinstall it. But if there is nothing else to do what works I would do that ofc.

Comment: have you considered try to find your LastPass password in the cache here is a artictle about how it is done http://securityxploded.com/googlechromesecrets.php

Comment: Thanks for the link! No I didn't try it. However, I did something else to make Chrome working again. I used `CCleaner` to delete my browser data. Somehow this worked. And my LP password was still saved. I just don't understand why deleting browser data with Chrome didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered, and my "fix" worked, here is the solution.

I used a CCleaner (without trying to advertise) to clear all the browser data. After that it worked again. Probably a reinstall would've done the same, but as I said, I wanted to keep my extension data etc.